# How can I see all tech tree nodes?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'd like to work towards some specific parts in the KSP Career/Science tech tree, but I have no idea where they are. Is there some setting in game (perhaps with a mod) or online resource I can use to show me everything to figure out what's where?

Answer (score 3):

The official tree is on Wiki, under http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Technology_tree - no surprise.

If you are using tree selection modules, then you must either read documentation for a mod, or do it good old way: Just play thorough all that technologies.